# Not able to find 'Area Plane' Brush mapping in Blender Texture painting Brush menu?

Tags: texture-painting

Not able to find 'Area Plane' Brush mapping in Blender Texture painting Brush menu. This is available for Sculpt Mode why not in Texture paint mode?[image: Not able to find 'Area Plane' Brush mapping in Blender Texture painting Brush menu. This is available for Sculpt Mode why not in Texture paint mode?]

Comment: View Plane isn't what you want?

Comment: "The Flatten brush finds an ‘area plane’ located by default at the average height above/below the vertices within the brush area. The vertices are then pulled towards this plane. The inverse of the Flatten brush is the Contrast brush which pushes vertices up or down away from the brush plane."   This means that Area Plane is a calculation with geometry, and not applicable to Texture Paint. If you want to affect the paint through geometry, then see the use of Cavity masking. https://youtu.be/6Ac6LqBW9H0?t=103

Comment: According to Blender Manual, this mapping should align brush to surface normal. but it doesn't. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/texture_tex_mask.html

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if they added the brush area plane feature from sculpt mode to the paint mode.
Sculptris has a feature in its paint mode similar to the area plane feature in blender sculpting where the brush flows along the contours of the surface as if projected along the normal rather than from the camera view.
The brush projected along the normal view would prevent the stretching caused by the brush being projected from the camera view.
Another suggestion if its not already a part of Blender would be to add a bit of control over the falloff for the texture brush so that the texture does not paint past a curved face or edge.